# QPalette Button Role not being drawn as defined

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I'm running into a strange issue. I have a QLabel that I would like to have the same background as a default QPushButton or QComboBox. The way I did that was with this code:

```
self.table_label.setBackgroundRole(QPalette.Button)
self.table_label.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Now, if I change the color I'm looking for to QPalette.Shadow or QPalette.Highlight, it works fine. But when I use the code above in my application, the line edit background is the same as the base window color!

I went a little deeper, and realized that

```
my_application.palette().color(QPalette.Button)
```

also returns the background window color, and

```
my_button.palette().color(QPalette.Button)
```

even returns the window color. But somehow my buttons and comboboxes are drawn a different color! Where is this color stored?
I'm running Qt5 on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: From the Qt Docs: "Warning: Some styles do not use the palette for all drawing, for instance, if they make use of native theme engines. This is the case for both the Windows XP, Windows Vista, and the macOS styles".